How to match world units to mouse inputs in LibGDX?
I am trying to create a UI for a game that I'm making in LibGDX. However, when I use world units, the mouse input does not correspond correctly and is off depending on the screen size. How can I make sure that the mouse input is always the same as what we see on the screen?
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen {

    final ClientLauncher game;

    private Texture playButtonInactive;
    private Texture playButtonClicked;
    private Texture playButtonActive;
    
    // Camera and Viewport stuff
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Viewport viewport;
    Sprite theWorld;
    // World unit
    private static final float WORLD_WIDTH = 1920;
    private static final float WORLD_HEIGHT = 1080;



 float x = (float)ClientLauncher.width / 9;
 float y = (float)ClientLauncher.height / 2;
 if ((Gdx.input.getX() > x && Gdx.input.getX() < x + playButtonActive.getWidth()) && (Gdx.input.getY() < y - 100 && Gdx.input.getY() > y - 100 - playButtonActive.getHeight())){
            game.batch.draw(playButtonInactive,x,y + 100);
            if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){
                game.batch.draw(playButtonClicked,x,y + 100);
                game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
            }
        }
        else{
            game.batch.draw(playButtonActive,x,y + 100);
        }

the ClientLauncher has a width and height of 1920 and 1080 so it's the same as my world units.
Thank you!
This is only a quick demo so I am hard coding the values but I'm trying to understand the structure of world units and how to use them when drawing and have everything in sync.

This link should be very useful for you:
https://libgdx.com/wiki/graphics/2d/scene2d/scene2d
I suggest reading all of that wiki before you ask questions - it is not that large and does a great job of explaining almost every aspect of the framework.
Viewport is what you need, and it is explained on that page. It also explains how actor hit detection works, which is another problem of your code
